# decimal numbers for padding and margin

Tags: css

Can I use decimal numbers (`18.9` or `75.5`) for padding, margin or other styles? all browsers (such as `IE5`, `IE6`) support it?

Thanks.

Comment: ie5 - really ? =) use firebug for ie https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359. NOTE: if you have ie 9: copatability 7-9.

Comment: for what unit? wouldnt make much sense for pixels - right!?

Comment: You can't have half a pixel, that's like talking about half an electron. But it's legal to say it. Perhaps just for consistency, perhaps because pixels aren't always pixels. If you print a document, the browser will scale your pixels from screen resolution (typically 72 ppi) to printer resolution (usually 300 to 600 ppi). So "1px" really means maybe 6 printer pixels.

Comment: I don't see why this question got down-voted!!!1one I actually have a case where `padding: 8.6px 0` would be nice to have. And in Chrome that works just fine. Worried about other browsers, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it's an EM measurement, I don't see why not.  Not sure about IE5, but I'm pretty sure IE6 is supported for decimals.  Any browser that supports EM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they apply anywhere for measurements. They don't make a lot of sense if you're positioning something and using partial pixel measurements, but otherwise they're perfectly acceptable. Just remembe to specify the units. e.g.

```
height: 57; /* no units, will be treated as an error */
height: 57px; /* perfectly fine */
```